# Android handler & Looper.prepare() issue

Tags: android, graphics, runnable, looper

Im creating a space shooter game for android, im currently implementing the shooting methods but getting some problems i cant figure out when trying to create new shots and drawing them.

i have this method:

```
    public void createShot(int time){

     if(shotCreated==true && time<=0){
         System.out.println("Funkar");
         Shot temp = new Shot(shipX,700);
         System.out.println("Funkar2");
         shotList.add(temp);

     }else if(time>=10){
         tick=0;
     }
}
```

that is called from the run() method
But i get the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Iv'e tried researching it here on the forum but can quite figure out how to solve it, can someone help me out?

regards,
Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you run() method place these two line at the top

```
Looper.myLooper();
Looper.prepare();
```

Comment: Simple as that.. Works perfectly, Thanks!